# Compile error : cast void * failed in C/C++

Tags: c++, casting, compilation, makefile

I want to compile a project that I know works.

So I creat a Makefile to compile it, but when I make it I have this error:

```
invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘LIMITOR_3DSL_Limitor_32f* {aka LIMITOR_3DSL_Limitor_32f_tag*}’ [-fpermissive]
*ppStatus = ippMalloc(sizeof(LIMITOR_3DSL_Limitor_32f));
                                                      ^
```

It is really strange how could a void* can't be cast ?
Can the compiler be the problem ? I am using g++

Comment: Choose a language. This is one of the many differences between C and C++. Also, a cast and an implicit conversion are different things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Opposite to C in C++ you may not assign a pointer of type void * to a pointer of any other type because such an assignment is unsafe. You have to cast the pointer explicitly to the required type using a C or C++ form of casting.

For example

```
LIMITOR_3DSL_Limitor_32f *ppStatus = ( LIMITOR_3DSL_Limitor_32f * )ippMalloc( sizeof(LIMITOR_3DSL_Limitor_32f ) );
```

or

```
LIMITOR_3DSL_Limitor_32f *ppStatus = static_cast<LIMITOR_3DSL_Limitor_32f*>( ippMalloc(sizeof(LIMITOR_3DSL_Limitor_32f ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

`LIMITOR_3DSL_Limitor_32f* ppStatus = (LIMITOR_3DSL_Limitor_32f*)ippMalloc(sizeof(LIMITOR_3DSL_Limitor_32f));`

In C/C++ we should cast type explicitly. ippMalloc will return a `void *` pointer, so we should cast it from `void *` to `LIMITOR_3DSL_Limitor_32f*`

Comment: This is wrong. In C casting `void *` is prohibited (6.3.2.3/1). In C++ it is required.